# Cannot change href value of a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, ejs

Im trying to change my href value, but it doesn't seem to be changing at all. I've tried both jQuery and javascript method and neither work.

```
<a type="button" class="view_me btn btn-primary" href="#">View Full</a>
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".click_row", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var _self = $(this);
  userId = _self.data('id');
  var newLink = '/users/view/' + userId //I'd like to eventually use this as new href link

  $(".view_me").prop("href", "www.google.com"); // Tried testing with a simple webpage

  // document.getElementById('view_test').href = "www.google.com"; // Tried this as well, doesn't work

  console.log(newLink)
});
```

Any suggestion would help. I'm using jQuery 3.2.1

Comment: `www.google.com` isn't a valid URL. Try `http://www.google.com` instead

Comment: where is `view_test` and `click_row`

Comment: `<a type="button" class="view_me btn btn-primary" href="#">View Full</a>`  does not have the id `view_test`.

Comment: add an [mcve] html to reproduce the issue

Comment: you need to add `id="view_test"` to your anchor element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few issues that were impeding the intended behavior.  First,  your `click` function wasn't being called because it was looking for the `click_row` class; I believe you may have meant for this to be the `view_me` class instead.
Second, you need to add `https://` to the beginning of the URL to have it redirect properly.  Lastly, you needed to set the `href` property of the link in your code that had the *class* `view_me`, not the *id* `view_me`.

EDIT:  Also, delete `e.preventDefault()` or else you can only open the link in a new tab.

The following JS code fixes these issues and produces the desired behavior:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".view_me", function (e) {

        //e.preventDefault();

        var _self = $(this);
        userId = _self.data('id');

        var newLink = '/users/view/' + userId
        $(".view_me").prop("href", "https://www.google.com");

        console.log(newLink);

   });
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2m0297j1/

Comment: This is strange. I can't left click the a tag, but when I open it in another tab it'll work. Thank you for your solution, but the end goal here is to change href link to a parameter.

Comment: Figured it out. e.preventDefault()  was causing the weird behavior

Comment: OMG THANK YOU <3